# How to run a webscraper continuously until interrupted

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=40.71455000000003&lon=-74.00713999999994#.XxWVcSgzbIU")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
week = soup.find(id='seven-day-forecast-list')
items = week.find_all(class_='tombstone-container')

'''
print(items[1].find(class_='period-name').get_text())
print(items[1].find(class_='short-desc').get_text())
print(items[1].find(class_='temp').get_text())
'''
#doing the above with list comprehesion
while(1):
    period_names=[item.find(class_='period-name').get_text() for item in items]
    short_descrpition=[item.find(class_='short-desc').get_text() for item in items]
    temp_names=[item.find(class_='temp').get_text() for item in items]

    weather_stuff = pd.DataFrame({
        'period':period_names,
        'short_descrpition': short_descrpition,
        'temperature':temp_names,
        })
    weather_stuff.to_csv('weather.csv')
```

Can I use while(1) to keep on updating the weather.csv file until I interrupt the program?

Comment: In order to keep updating, you need to keep sending requests to the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to keep updating, you need to keep sending request to the website and update the csv. In your case, you are overwriting the csv file

```
import pandas as pd
import requests, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

count = 0

while 1:
    page = requests.get("https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=40.71455000000003&lon=-74.00713999999994#.XxWVcSgzbIU")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    week = soup.find(id='seven-day-forecast-list')
    items = week.find_all(class_='tombstone-container')

    period_names=[item.find(class_='period-name').get_text() for item in items]
    short_descrpition=[item.find(class_='short-desc').get_text() for item in items]
    temp_names=[item.find(class_='temp').get_text() for item in items]

    weather_stuff = pd.DataFrame({
        'period':period_names,
        'short_descrpition': short_descrpition,
        'temperature':temp_names,
        })
    weather_stuff.to_csv('weather.csv')
    count+=1
    print(count)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Output is number of times, the request is sent. I have also put a sleep between 2 continuous calls

Comment: What do 2 continuous calls mean? Also, you didn't import time guess that would give an error. And why are we using count here?

Comment: @ShubhamPrashar I have imported `time` module, look line number 2. 2 continuous calls means calls made inside the while loop. We need to have some mercy on the website